# Orika mapper exception

Tags: java, exception, orika

I use Orika mapper for mapping Hibernate entities to webservice entities. It works perfect, but it sometimes throws the following exception. I don't know how to resolve it. I use tomcat.

```
ma.glasnost.orika.MappingException: ma.glasnost.orika.impl.generator.CompilerStrategy$SourceCodeGenerationException: class com.example.hibernate.Product$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$b9465553 is not accessible
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.generator.MapperGenerator.build(MapperGenerator.java:95)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.DefaultMapperFactory.buildMapper(DefaultMapperFactory.java:1046)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.DefaultMapperFactory.registerClassMap(DefaultMapperFactory.java:880)
    at com.example.mapping.EntityMapper.map(EntityMapper.java:50)
    at com.example.mapping.EntityMapper.map(EntityMapper.java:69)
    at com.example.ws.helpers.store.ProductHelper.getAll(ProductHelper.java:53)
    at com.example.ws.StoreWebService.getProducts(StoreWebService.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.InstanceResolver$1.invoke(InstanceResolver.java:246)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:146)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointMethodHandler.invoke(EndpointMethodHandler.java:257)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:95)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:629)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:588)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:573)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:470)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:295)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:515)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:285)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:143)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doGet(WSServletDelegate.java:155)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doPost(WSServletDelegate.java:189)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet.doPost(WSServlet.java:76)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1571)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: ma.glasnost.orika.impl.generator.CompilerStrategy$SourceCodeGenerationException: class com.example.hibernate.Product$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$b9465553 is not accessible
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.generator.JavassistCompilerStrategy.assureTypeIsAccessible(JavassistCompilerStrategy.java:178)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.generator.MapperGenerator.build(MapperGenerator.java:55)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: orika_shaded.javassist.NotFoundException: com.example.hibernate.Product$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$b9465553
    at orika_shaded.javassist.ClassPool.get(ClassPool.java:450)
    at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.generator.JavassistCompilerStrategy.assureTypeIsAccessible(JavassistCompilerStrategy.java:176)
    ... 44 more
```